# Freeform won't accept email addresses without .tld and breaks error_page

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, error, email

I have a form with an input field.  The form works fine as long as someone submits an email with a tld (e.g., john@example.com).  Unfortunately, we need it to be able to accept emails for local domains too (e.g., john@localdomain).  If someone submits that as an email address, Freeform doesn't submit the data and, instead, just redirects to domain.com/undefined which, we assume, is due to some specific error.  We tried to add error_page="form/error" to the Freeform call which should pull up our error page template.  I know the template exists, because pulling up domain.com/form/error pulls up the unparsed template, yet Freeform instead just hangs on submit.  The "Submit" button gets "visibility:hidden" applied to it, but then it just sits there and nothing happens.  Any ideas how to fix this issue or what could be causing it?

Comment: Have you considered changing that field to just a regular text box, and not validate as email? You could then probably make a custom extension that checks if the field value passes a regular expression for emails, and then if not, checks if it passes a regular expression like `/(a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.)*\@(a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.)/` (that was untested, but basically looks for string@string).

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this.  I disabled freeform's validation and then setup validation using regexp similarly to that.  We ran into another issue with freeform's validation which is what prompted me to just replace it with another validator.